# i have created a inquiry form for single product !!! magento 2

Tags: magento2

```
                <------------------ ACTUAL FORM ------------------->

                <form class="form contact"
                  action="https://isolonline.com/contactus/front/save/"
                  id="contact-form"
                  name="contact-form"
                  onsubmit="return myFunction()"
                  method="post"
                  data-hasrequired="* Required Fields"
                  data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="field name required input_outer">
                    <label class="label" for="sku"><span>Product SKU</span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input name="name" id="sku" placeholder="Product SKU Number" title="Product SKU Number"  class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field email required input_outer">
                     <label class="label" for="email"><span>Email Address</span></label>
                      <div class="control">
                        <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" title="Email"  class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                      <div class="field telephone input_outer">
                       <label class="label" for="telephone"><span>Your Phone Number</span></label>
                        <div class="control">
                          <input name="phone" id="telephone" placeholder="Phone Number" title="Phone Number" class="input-text" type="text" />
                        </div>
                      </div>

                       <div class="field subject input_outer">
                         <label class="label" for="Offer"><span>Make An Offer</span></label>
                          <div class="control">
                            <input name="subject" id="Offer" placeholder="Make Your Offer" title="Your Offer" class="input-text" type="text" />
                          </div>
                           </div>
                            </div>

                          <br>

                      <div class="actions-toolbar">
                        <div class="primary">
                          <input type="hidden" name="ip" id="ip" value="168.211.75.125" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="country" id="country" value="United States" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
                          <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  title="Submit" class="action submit primary">
                            <span>Submit</span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    </form>
```

<------------------ FORM FUNCTIONS ------------------->

```
                   <div>
                    <div class="field name required input_outer">

                      <div class="control">
                        <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($this->nametittle()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($this->nametittle()) ?>"  class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field email required input_outer">

                      <div class="control">
                        <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($this->emailtittle()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($this->emailtittle()) ?>"  class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php if($this->phonetittle() != '') {?>
                      <div class="field telephone input_outer">

                        <div class="control">
                          <input name="phone" id="telephone" placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($this->phonetittle()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($this->phonetittle()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <?php } ?>

                      <?php if($this->subjecttittle() != '') {?>
                        <div class="field subject input_outer">

                          <div class="control">
                            <input name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($this->subjecttittle()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($this->subjecttittle()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                      </div>
                      <div class="field comment required">

                        <div class="control">
                          <textarea name="message" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($this->messagetittle()) ?>" id="comment" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($this->messagetittle()) ?>" class="input-text" cols="1" rows="6" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <?php if($this->isCaptchaEnabled()) { ?>
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" name="recaptcha" id="recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $this->getsitekey(); ?>"></div>

                        <?php } ?>


                       <!-- <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?> -->

                      </fieldset>
                      <div class="actions-toolbar">
                        <div class="primary">
                          <input type="hidden" name="ip" id="ip" value="<?php echo $ip; ?>" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="country" id="country" value="<?php echo $country; ?>" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
                          <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($this->buttontext()) ?>" class="action submit primary">
                            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($this->buttontext()) ?></span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </form>
```

Comment: Could you share the file from where the mail function is triggered

Comment: You can set hidden field for product title and SKU and while getting the post value you can get those fields and set it in email template..

Comment: Okay here a link to site,below is a button to make an offer (https://isolonline.com/323956074858.html) and i have not created this form with magento default email template , i have used contact from exttension and changes it fields

Comment: ok here a wetransfer to a file (https://we.tl/t-GYlpLdlAJc) it contain 2 piece of code (1) first piece of code is actual form and (2) second piece is form function, Hope is have share a right file , just need it to have product title value as hidden field , i am new to magento and i am having hard time to figure out files and code !!!

Comment: Could you be able toshare the code.. I couldn't access the wetransfer..

Comment: ok i have change my answer and also share the code !!!

Comment: ACTUAL FORM will be displayed in product page right? when submitted all the details from that form will be posted ?

Comment: yes that's exectly what i want

Comment: Did you able to get product object in that form? Did you used xml to show that form in product page?